# ImageView doesn't insert camera picture in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, imageview, onactivityresult

I'm standing in front of a big problem, I already asked many people but nobody could help me.

As in the title, I've made an Android-App with three fragments.
In one fragment I want to open a camera, when a empty ImageView is clicked.
After taking a picture the ImageView should show the captured image from the camera.

The app opens the camera and also takes a pic, but doesn't insert the picture in the ImageView.

This Code is in my Fragment

`public class FragmentNew extends Fragment {`

```
public static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_1 = 1;
public static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_2 = 2;
public static final int SELECT_PIC_REQUEST_1 = 3;
public static final int SELECT_PIC_REQUEST_2 = 4;

ImageView imageView1;
ImageView imageView2;
View rootView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   final View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new,container, false);
   imageView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_pic1);
   imageView2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_pic2);

   return rootView;
}


public void check(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data,ImageView imv1,ImageView imv2) {

    Log.d("Name", "onActivityResult");
    switch(requestCode){
        case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_1:
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras().get("data")!=null){
                   Log.d("TAG1","Photo pic1"); 
                   Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                    
                   imv1.setImageBitmap(photo);
                   Log.d("TAG1","Photo pic1 was set");

            }
            break;

        case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_2:
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras().get("data")!=null){
                   Log.d("TAG2","Photo pic2"); 
                   Bitmap photo2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                   //imv2.setImageBitmap(photo2);
                   imv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255));
                   Log.d("TAG2","Photo pic2 was set");
             }
            break;

            default:
                Log.d("Error","It doesn't work");
    }
}
```

`}`

MainActivity:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.image_accept:
        EditText text;
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Decision "+ text.getText().toString()+" was created!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.image_pic1:
        Builder builderpic1 = new Builder(this);
        builderpic1.setTitle("Pick a Pic")
               .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
               .setItems(R.array.selection, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        //Intent galeryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                        //       "content://media/internal/images/media")); 
                        //       startActivity(galeryintent);

                        //Intent intent = new Intent();
                        //intent.setType("image/*");
                        //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PIC_REQUEST_1);

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PIC_REQUEST_1);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, FragmentNew.SELECT_PIC_REQUEST_1);        
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent photointent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(photointent, FragmentNew.CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_1);

                        break;
                    case 2:     
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://images.google.com/"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        break;
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
               .show();
        break;
    case R.id.image_pic2:
        Builder builderpic2 = new Builder(this);
        builderpic2.setTitle("Pick a Pic")
               .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
               .setItems(R.array.selection, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        Intent galeryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                                 "content://media/internal/images/media")); 
                                 startActivity(galeryintent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent photointent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(photointent2, FragmentNew.CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_2);
                        break;
                    case 2:     
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://images.google.com/"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                        break;
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
               .show();
        break;
    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment myFragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_new);

    ImageView imv1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_pic1);
    ImageView imv2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_pic2);

    ((FragmentNew)myFragment).check(requestCode, resultCode, data,imv1,imv2);
}
```

The BackgroundColor is just set to check if the problem is in the bitmap, but the BackgroundColor doesn't change too, so I think the problem is, that the fragment doesn't find the ImageView in the onActivityResult().
The Log.d are shown in the console, but the ImageView stays empty.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't think that your image view was not found, or it would be null and you would have a NullPointerException at imv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255)); So at least it is not your problem yet. Does it output your Log.d("TAG2","Photo pic2"); ?

Comment: Yes the output is printed in the console

Comment: It does the Log output but doesn't set the background? Can you see the previous background? Are you sure about the dimensions of your ImageView?

Comment: Yes, the Log output is printed, but the background doesn't change, and the imageview is like before the camera should capture a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but I can't find your onActivityResult method and where you set the ImageView OnclickListener. Maybe they are in your activity class.
Your check method look a lot like an onActivityResult method except for the ImageView args. Did you call your check method yourself ? and was it in your onActivityResult?

Maybe you have done something like this and then I wouldn't know what is wrong in your code :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    mFragment.check(requestCode, resultCode, data, mImageView1, mImageView2);
}
```

Actually if you don't mind saving the picture on the device, you could also do something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST_1);
```

And in your onActivityResult :

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFile.getPath());
mImageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

But I think that your way should also work, I just never tried it.

Could you please add more of your code so we can see where you call startActivityForResult and your onActivityResult Method ?

Comment: I edit new Code, sorry the check() function was earlier a onActivityResult() function.